# multiprocessing do not work

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am working on Ubuntu 12 with 8 CPU3 as reported by the System monitor.

the testing code is

```
    import multiprocessing as mp

    def square(x):
        return x**2


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool=mp.Pool(processes=4)
        pool.map(square,range(100000000))
        pool.close()
        # for i in range(100000000):
        #    square(i)
```

The problem is:

1) All workload seems to be scheduled to just one core, which gets close to 100% utilization, despite the fact that several processes are started. Occasionally all workload migrates to another core but the workload is never distributed among them.

2) without multiprocessing is faster

```
    for i in range(100000000):
        square(i)
```

I have read the similar questions on stackoverflow like:
[Python multiprocessing utilizes only one core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905264/python-multiprocessing-utilizes-only-one-core)

still got no applied result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are using is way too short (i.e. doesn't take enough time to compute), so you spend all your time in the synchronization between processes, that has to be done in a serial manner (so why not on a single processor). Try this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def square(x):
    for i in range(10000):
         j = i**2
    return x**2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # pool=mp.Pool(processes=4)
    # pool.map(square,range(1000))
    # pool.close()
    for i in range(1000):
        square(i)
```

You will see that suddenly the multiprocessing works well: it takes ~2.5 seconds to accomplish, while it will take 10s without it.

**Note:** If using python 2, you might want to replace all the `range` by `xrange`

**Edit:** I replaced `time.sleep` by a CPU-intensive but useless calculation

**Addendum:** In general, for multi-CPU applications, you should try to make each CPU do as much work as possible without returning to the same process. In a case like yours, this means splitting the range into almost-equal sized lists, one per CPU and send them to the various CPUs.

Comment: Even if this proves that multiprocessing can spawn multiple processes, this code will not necessarily use more than one CPU, it could fit all the processes on the same CPU while the other processes are sleeping. Even if you set the script affinity to use a single CPU you will still see the speedup here.

Comment: @enrico.bacis Fair enough. See my changes ... I hope you are now convinced!

Comment: I was convinced also before, I was only saying that the example was not really a parallel *computation* but more like parallel *sleep*, that can be performed on any machine that support context switch. But of course I'm convinced that python multiprocessing.Pool works ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
pool.map(square, range(100000000))
```

Before invoking the `map` function, it has to create a list with *100000000* elements, and this is done by a single process, That's why you see a single core working.

Use a generator instead, so each core can pop a number out of it and you should see the speedup:

```
pool.map(square, xrange(100000000))
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't sufficient simply to import the multiprocessing library to make use of multiple processes to schedule your work. You actually have to create processes too!

Your work is currently scheduled to a single core because you haven't done so, and so your program is a single process with a single thread.

Naturally, when you start a new process to simply square a number, you are going to get slower performance. The overhead of process creation makes sure of that. So your process pool will very likely take longer than a singe-process run.

Comment: I assume the OP uncomments the part using the ``multiprocess`` module before evaluating it.

Comment: The thread pool was in the commented part, probably because it was faster like this, but I agree that it was not clear.