# How to fully take advantage of multi-cores by python

Tags: python, multithreading, cpu, cpu-usage

I used python to execute this program on Ubuntu

```
import thread
import time

# Define a function for the thread
def print_time( threadName, delay):
   count = 0
   while True:
      count += 1

# Create two threads as follows
try:
   for index in xrange(1,50000):
     thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-" + str(index), 0, ) )

except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"

while 1:
   pass
```

I want all 8 cores are all 100% usage, but through System Monitor i only got 50% usage of  the first 4 cores and 25% usage of the last 4 cores.
How can i make all 8 cores with 100% usage by python?

Comment: Won't that make 50000 new threads? Also, threading will only create multiple threads within your single Python process. It sounds like you want to use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Comment: Do you mean that only multiprocessing can have up to 100% usage of CPU?

Comment: On a multi-core PC, yes. This link might help with that [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784389/using-100-of-all-cores-with-python-multiprocessing].

Comment: Then how does OS handle the upper limit cpu usage of one process? Does all OS set it to 50%, or i can configure it?

Comment: Not sure, I guess that would be OS dependent and have not much to do with your Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will get you started. You'd need to tweak `num_processes` in order to match your hardware.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def slow_func():
    while True:
        for i in xrange(99999):
            j = i*i

def main():
    num_processes = 4

    for _ in range(num_processes):
        process = mp.Process(target = slow_func)
        process.daemon = True
        process.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Edit:** this works for me on Windows with 4 cores and gives 4x 25% processor usage.

To compare to the threading module, you can `import threading` and replace the line `process = mp.Process(target = slow_func)` with `process = threading.Thread(target = slow_func)`. You should find it uses only one of your cores.