# What is the easiest way to make maximum cpu usage for nested for-loops?

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, multiprocessing, nested-loops

I have code that makes unique combinations of elements. There are 6 types, and there are about 100 of each. So there are 100^6 combinations. Each combination has to be calculated, checked for relevance and then either be discarded or saved.

The relevant bit of the code looks like this:

```
def modconffactory():
for transmitter in totaltransmitterdict.values():
    for reciever in totalrecieverdict.values():
        for processor in totalprocessordict.values():
            for holoarray in totalholoarraydict.values():
                for databus in totaldatabusdict.values():
                    for multiplexer in totalmultiplexerdict.values():
                        newconfiguration = [transmitter, reciever, processor, holoarray, databus, multiplexer]
                        data_I_need = dosomethingwith(newconfiguration)
                        saveforlateruse_if_useful(data_I_need)
```

Now this takes a long time and that is fine, but now I realize this process (making the configurations and then calculations for later use) is only using 1 of my 8 processor cores at a time.

I've been reading up about multithreading and multiprocessing, but I only see examples of different processes, not how to multithread one process. In my code I call two functions: 'dosomethingwith()' and 'saveforlateruse_if_useful()'. I could make those into separate processes and have those run concurrently to the for-loops, right?

**But what about the for-loops themselves? Can I speed up that one process? Because that is where the time consumption is. (<-- This is my main question)**

Is there a cheat? for instance compiling to C and then the os multithreads automatically?

Comment: You will find your solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784389/using-100-of-all-cores-with-python-multiprocessing

Comment: I don't see how I can put the for-loops into an pipeline as is being done in that anwser you refer to. I read that already, but I don't see how that can help me? Can you explain?

Comment: Read up the multiprocessing docs (python's standard-lib) or the docs of the library joblib. As the first loop is of size 100 and you have 8 <= 100 cpus, just parallelize this outer loop (joblib's first example should be enough; basically: define a function which does everything except the outer loop; this a-priori chosen value is an argument). (Also: the last sentence shows a clear lack of understanding in regards to programming, OS, processors. Maybe read some introductionary course first.)

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see where it's spending most of its time? I would think it would be in the `dosomethingwith(newconfiguration)` calls. If that's the case you could run that as a separate process and have those put their results in a `Queue` shared with the main process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I only see examples of different processes, not how to multithread one process*

There is multithreading in Python, but it is very ineffective because of GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). So if you want to use all of your processor cores, if you want concurrency, you have no other choice than use multiple processes, which can be done with `multiprocessing` module (well, you also could use another language without such problems)

Approximate example of multiprocessing usage for your case:

```
import multiprocessing

WORKERS_NUMBER = 8

def modconffactoryProcess(generator, step, offset, conn):
    """
    Function to be invoked by every worker process.

    generator: iterable object, the very top one of all you are iterating over, 
    in your case, totalrecieverdict.values()

    We are passing a whole iterable object to every worker, they all will iterate 
    over it. To ensure they will not waste time by doing the same things 
    concurrently, we will assume this: each worker will process only each stepTH 
    item, starting with offsetTH one. step must be equal to the WORKERS_NUMBER, 
    and offset must be a unique number for each worker, varying from 0 to 
    WORKERS_NUMBER - 1

    conn: a multiprocessing.Connection object, allowing the worker to communicate 
    with the main process
    """
    for i, transmitter in enumerate(generator):
        if i % step == offset:
            for reciever in totalrecieverdict.values():
                for processor in totalprocessordict.values():
                    for holoarray in totalholoarraydict.values():
                        for databus in totaldatabusdict.values():
                            for multiplexer in totalmultiplexerdict.values():
                                newconfiguration = [transmitter, reciever, processor, holoarray, databus, multiplexer]
                                data_I_need = dosomethingwith(newconfiguration)
                                saveforlateruse_if_useful(data_I_need)
    conn.send('done')


def modconffactory():
    """
    Function to launch all the worker processes and wait until they all complete 
    their tasks
    """
    processes = []
    generator = totaltransmitterdict.values()
    for i in range(WORKERS_NUMBER):
        conn, childConn = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=modconffactoryProcess, args=(generator, WORKERS_NUMBER, i, childConn))
        process.start()
        processes.append((process, conn))
    # Here we have created, started and saved to a list all the worker processes
    working = True
    finishedProcessesNumber = 0
    try:
        while working:
            for process, conn in processes:
                if conn.poll():  # Check if any messages have arrived from a worker
                    message = conn.recv()
                    if message == 'done':
                        finishedProcessesNumber += 1
            if finishedProcessesNumber == WORKERS_NUMBER:
                working = False
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Aborted')
```

You can adjust `WORKERS_NUMBER` to your needs.

Same with `multiprocessing.Pool`:

```
import multiprocessing

WORKERS_NUMBER = 8

def modconffactoryProcess(transmitter):
    for reciever in totalrecieverdict.values():
        for processor in totalprocessordict.values():
            for holoarray in totalholoarraydict.values():
                for databus in totaldatabusdict.values():
                    for multiplexer in totalmultiplexerdict.values():
                        newconfiguration = [transmitter, reciever, processor, holoarray, databus, multiplexer]
                        data_I_need = dosomethingwith(newconfiguration)
                        saveforlateruse_if_useful(data_I_need)


def modconffactory():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(WORKERS_NUMBER)
    pool.map(modconffactoryProcess, totaltransmitterdict.values())
```

You probably would like to use `.map_async` instead of `.map`

Both snippets do the same, but I would say in the first one you have more control over the program.

I suppose the second one is the easiest, though :)

But the first one should give you the idea of what is happening in the second one

`multiprocessing` docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 0):

you can run your function in this way:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
   p = Pool(5)
   print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers