# Python multiprocessing: Extracting results

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to run a bunch of simulations in Python, so I tried implementing it with multiprocessing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multiprocessing as mp
import psutil

from Functions import hist, exp_fit, exponential

N = 100000  # Number of observations
tau = 13362.525  # decay rate to simulate
iterations = 1  # Number of iterations for each process
bin_size = 1*1e9 # in nanoseconds

def spawn(queue):
    results = []
    procs = list()
    n_cpus = psutil.cpu_count()
    for cpu in range(n_cpus):
        affinity = [cpu]
        d = dict(affinity=affinity)
        p = mp.Process(target=run_child, args=[queue], kwargs=d)
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)
    for p in procs:
        results.append(queue.get)
        p.join()
        print('joined')
    return results

def run_child(queue, affinity):
    proc = psutil.Process()  # get self pid
    proc.cpu_affinity(affinity)
    print(affinity)
    np.random.seed()
    for i in range(iterations):
        time = np.sort(-np.log(np.random.uniform(size=N)) * tau) * 1e9
        n, bins = hist(time, bin_size)
        fit = exp_fit(n, bins, silent=True)
        queue.put(fit)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    output = mp.Queue()
    plt.figure()
    results = spawn(output)
    bins = range(1000)
    for fit in results:
        plt.plot(bins, exponential(fit.params, bins), 'k-', alpha=0.1)
    plt.show()
```

My attempt is heavily inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371568) answer I found while trying to find a solution myself, where the affinity of each process is manually set as numpy apparently changes the default behaviour (it only runs on a single core if this is not done).

I think the code mostly works; each process performs a simulation and fit as intended, but I cannot figure out how to extract the results. As it is now, the queue.put(fit) in the run_child method seems to cause the program to halt.

Any ideas as to why this happens, and how to fix it?

Comment: If the `queue.put(fit)` blocks the execution, that means that the queue is waiting to get a free slot to insert the fit variable. It will block if the queue is full.

Comment: And are sure about the `results.append(queue.get)` ? It might be `results.append(queue.get())`

Comment: That was an obvious mistake - I've tried a few different approaches, and must've missed it the last time around. Correcting it doesn't fix the hangs, though.
How do I know if the queue is full? Is there some fixed storage capacity I have to be aware of?

Comment: Weird thing, I tried your code by replacing your `hist` and `exp_fit` by `time.sleep(5)` and everything worked fine. Are you sure it's `queue.put(fit)` that is blocking your code ?

Comment: And a queue can have a maximum size if you set it in the constructor. But, in your case, it should have an infinite size so it won't be the queue that is blocking your code.

Comment: I found the problem! The queues do not support the fit data type (OptimizeResult), so by extracting only the fitting parameters I needed from the fit, putting them in a list and passing them to the queue worked like a charm.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! Glad you got it sorted. Please avoid answering questions in the comments, instead use the answer box below. [It's OK to answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was trying to pass an OptimizeResult data type to the queue. Extracting only the necessary data from the fit and passing that instead worked like a charm.

Thanks to Pierre-Nicolas Piquin for helping solve it!